# I dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. If I upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 Technical Preview, will that overwrite my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I just want to make sure before I begin the installation process of the [Windows 10 Technical Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/preview-iso) that when it's installed, it will limit itself to overwriting my Windows 7 partition, not my Ubuntu partition.

Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went for it and there weren't any problems. In my GRUB menu it still has "Windows 7" as the option, but it boots to Windows 10 Tech Preview.

Answer (score 0):

From Reddit:

> When I installed it, it didn't overwrite my Ubuntu partition but it
>   destroyed the GRUB bootloader and made Ubuntu unusable. You may want
>   to use a diffrent hard drive just to be safe.
>
> Windows tends to like overwriting the MBR. If it does, to fix it just
>   grab a boot-repair image. That'll rewrite your MBR so it invokes Grub
>   again. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/2tkgvr/i_dual_boot_ubuntu_1404_and_windows_7_if_i/)